# Requiring a particular file extension in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this reg ex

```
var regex = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/;
```

This is used on a field for specifying image urls, so I need the last part of the url to be either .jpg, .png, .gif etc

How can i modify the regex to test this?

Thanks

(regex used: http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the)

Comment: This pattern is long and inefficient! Matching the protocol with `[A-Za-z]{3,9}` is a joke! Forget it and write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending your existing regex with `\.(jpg|png|gif)`

Basically what this does is it checks for a dot (`\.`, must be escaped since its a special character), then checks if a string is followed by either `jpg`, `png`, or `gif`.

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) is a wonderful tool to play around with (I learned regex messing with it).

```
((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)\.(jpg|png|gif)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7yqaTW_g2DHsbUdJ)